# Npm config for upgrading from Angular 15 to Angular 16

Tags: angular, npm-install

I'm trying to upgrade from Angular 15 to Angular 16.

I had this config for version 15:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "~15.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~15.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "~15.0.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~15.0.4",
    "@angular/localize": "~15.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~15.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~15.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "~15.0.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^14.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "^15.0.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^15.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.5",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "15.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "15.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "15.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "15.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~15.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.30",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.43.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.43.0",
    "eslint": "^8.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^39.2.9",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.19",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "typescript": "~4.8.4"
   }
 }
```

This is my first attempt for the new config (in order to run Angular 16):

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "test-ci": "ng test --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "16.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "16.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~15.0.4",
    "@angular/localize": "~15.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~15.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~15.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "~15.0.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^14.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "^15.0.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^15.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "16.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "16.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "16.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "16.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "16.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "16.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "16.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^18.0.30",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.43.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.43.0",
    "eslint": "^8.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^39.2.9",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.19",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "typescript": "~4.9.4"
  }
}
```

However, this is what I'm getting when I run "npm install":

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: name@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.0.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"16.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"16.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@16.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^16.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"16.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Please guide me to get this to work. It could work with "--force" but I guess that's not what you want.

Comment: https://update.angular.io/

Comment: It's been a bit since I've done Angular but don't you have to manually install version 16 locally then you can run your config to update your application?

Comment: All angular versions should be at `~16.0.0`

Comment: @Pieterjan do you mean all "@angular*", "@angular-devkit", "@angular-eslint" ?

Comment: @Jojje don't ignore the first two comments, those are the valid answers.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks, but that page doesn't really help you with the package.json config that much..?

Comment: Also for updating packages you might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58167892/how-do-i-find-which-packages-are-dependent-on-angular-versions-higher-than-6-x

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75079863/12836822 - This may helpful to someone

Answer (score 1):

I followed the advice of @edjm , i.e I installed a separate Angular 16 app and compared the package versions. I used the versions provided in the new Angular 16 installation.

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.1.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^15.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "^16.0.2",
    "ngx-toastr": "^15.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~16.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~16.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~16.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~16.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "~16.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~16.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^18.0.30",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.43.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.43.0",
    "eslint": "^8.43.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^46.4.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.19",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "typescript": "~4.9.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For fix this problem you can do:

```bash
npm i --legacy-peer-deps
```

temporarily just to install package

Comment: This is not a good answer. It will silence the npm errors, but the application will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I installed a separate Angular 16 app and compared the package versions , everything it working

```
{
      "name": "name",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "test-ci": "ng test --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless",
        "lint": "ng lint"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^16.0.0",
        "@angular/common": "16.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^16.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "16.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~16.0.0",
        "@angular/localize": "~16.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~16.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~16.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "~16.0.0",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^15.0.0",
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
        "ngx-spinner": "^15.0.1",
        "ngx-toastr": "^15.0.0",
        "rxjs": "~7.5.5",
        "tslib": "^2.4.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.13.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "16.0.0",
        "@angular-eslint/builder": "16.0.0",
        "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "16.0.0",
        "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "16.0.0",
        "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^16.0.0",
        "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "16.0.0",
        "@angular/cli": "16.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "16.0.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.3",
        "@types/node": "^18.0.30",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.43.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.43.0",
        "eslint": "^8.28.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^39.2.9",
        "jasmine-core": "~4.1.0",
        "karma": "~6.3.19",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
        "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "~5.0.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
        "karma-junit-reporter": "^2.0.1",
        "typescript": "~4.9.4"
      }
    }
```